# how to remove a line of text from pcl file

Tags: printing, command

I have a pcl file. I want to remove a line of data from pcl file. I don't have pcl line of data but i have normal text and my text is "*c40E*c45Ec46E*c107E*c125E*c35Ec40E*c45E*c46E*c50E*c60E*c125Ec35E*c40E*c50E*c88E".

I want to remove this line of code from pcl file.

Comment: *c40E*c45Ec46E*c107E*c125E*c35Ec40E*c45E*c46E*c50E*c60E*c125Ec35E*c40E*c50E*c88E

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show how you've attempted to solve the problem and what went wrong/didn't work?